# Normal proper subgroup of product of finite simple groups is isomorphic to one of them

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering if anyone can give me a hint/sketch for the following problem, if possible using elementary group theory methods (I am familiar with the material of, say, chapters 1-4 in Rotman).

Let $G_{1},G_{2}$ be finite simple groups. If $H\triangleleft G_{1}\times G_{2}=G$
  is a proper subgroup (not $\{1\}$   or $G$ ), then $H$   is isomorphic to $G_{1}$
  or to $G_{2}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $H$ is normal in $G$, therefore, $H\cap G_{1}$ is normal in $G_{1}$.  Likewise, $H\cap G_{2}$ is normal in $G_{2}$.  You know that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are simple, so ...

Comment: Thanks...I assume that $H_i := H\cap G_i$ means the set of left coordinates of $H$, in which case it is not guaranteed that $H =  H_2 \times H_2$. (If, alternatively $H_i$ means $H_i \cap G_i \times {1}$ then a similar problem arises). So I don't know how to proceed from that. But I found a proof using the Jordan-Holder theorem. Posting...

Comment: sorry there was a typo I meant not guaranteed that $H = H_1 \times H_2 $.

Answer (score 0):

OK this might be an overkill, but here goes: $G$ is solvable via composition series $ \{1\} \leq G_1 \leq G$. Let $N \triangleleft G$ non-trivial, then $\{1\}  \triangleleft N \triangleleft G$ is a subnormal series, which by Schrier's theorem can be extended to a composition series. But by Jordan-Holder, this series must be equivalent to the first one above, i.e. the two series have isomorphic factors, which means that either $N \cong N/1 \cong G/G_1 \cong G_2$ or  $N \cong G_1/ \{1\} \cong G_1$, as required.

Comment: This is overkill really. The answer of James is perfectly correct, though in the form of a hint: Since we are told that $H \neq G,1,$ and we have to look a the possibilities for $H \cap G_{1}$ and $H \cap G_{2}.$  The most difficult case to think about is when $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are both Abelian, so cyclic of prime order.